# Ellipsis Tooltip CSS

Tags: css, sass

For the below given html, for class refNum, I want to truncate the string and show ellipsis but when we hover over the p tag (refNum), want to show the whole text.

```
<div class="right">
          <p class="name">Chrishtoper Benson</p>
          <p class="refNum">
        123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
Reference T
          </p>
   </div>
```

Below is the given scss used,

```
         .right {
                    flex: 2;
                    @include flexbox;
                    @include flex-direction(column);
                    justify-content: flex-end;
                    .name {
                        text-align: right;
                        font-size: 13px;
                        word-break: break-word;
                    }
                    .refNum {
                        text-align: right;
                        font-size: 10px;
                        line-height: 20px;
                        width: 100px;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        text-overflow: ellipsis;
                        position: relative;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    }
                    .refNum:hover::before {
                      content: attr(refNum);
                      position: absolute;
                      bottom: -46px;
                      padding: 10px;
                      background: #000;
                      color: #fff;
                      font-size: 14px;
                      white-space: nowrap;
                    }
                }
```

Please help with the same, as this doesn't work. Thank you in advance.
Also want to right-align the refNum.

Answer (score 1):

The below solution simply changes `overflow: hidden;` to `overflow: visible;` on hover:

```css
.right {
  flex: 2;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.right .name {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.right .refNum {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right .refNum:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <p class="name">Chrishtoper Benson</p>
  <p class="refNum">
    123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789 Reference T
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But this won't render properly on mobile devices. Is there another way

Comment: @ApoorvaOjha -- what is your desired visual outcome for mobile devices?  To have it break to multiple lines?  Also, remember that most mobile devices are touchscreens, which have no true "hover" because they have no cursor (although most will emulate a hover on a tap action if one is wired up).

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
        $(document).on("mouseenter",".tooltip-check", function(e){
            if(this.scrollWidth > $(e.target).outerWidth()){
                $(this).attr("title", $(this).text());
            }
            else{
              $(this).removeAttr("title");
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.right {
     flex: 2;
     justify-content: flex-end;
}
 .right .name {
     text-align: right;
     font-size: 13px;
     word-break: break-word;
}
 .right .refNum {
     text-align: right;
     font-size: 10px;
     line-height: 20px;
     width: 100px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .right .refNum:hover::before {
     content: attr(refNum);
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -46px;
     padding: 10px;
     background: #000;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 14px;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right">
          <p class="name">Chrishtoper Benson</p>
          <p class="refNum tooltip-check">
        123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
Reference T
          </p>
   </div>
```